# Order By Tree with Parent Consideration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

I have a document structure like this within Kentico:

- Container 1

  - Child 1
- Container 2

  - Child 2
- Container 3

  - Child 3
- Container 4

  - Child 4

We're currently selecting all "Child" documents and then sorting by NodeLevel, NodeOrder, NodeName. This results in a list of the children sorted by NodeName (alphabetically) since they all have equivalent NodeLevel and NodeOrder.

Is there a way to sort them that takes their Container into consideration? We want them to be in the order Child 1, Child 2, Child 3, Child 4.

Update: I should have mentioned early on that we're using an MVC app with Kentico. As such, I'm not making direct database queries, but using the Document Providers supplied by Kentico. This limits me to using methods associated with DocumentQuery objects and LINQ expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with Kentico support, we came up with a slightly cleaner solution:

```
.OrderBy(node => node.Parent.NodeOrder)
```

That seemed like the cleanest way to handle this, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your OrderBy clause:

```
CASE WHEN NodeLevel == 1 THEN NodeName ELSE '' END
```

So this would be in your ORDER BY property.  What is is doing is checking the node level if the node level of the document = 1 then it will sort it by NodeName, otherwise it won't sort it.  This will only order the NodeLevel 1 items.

See a similar answer I [posted here](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/smart-search-results-sorting-ascending-and-ignoring-empty-values)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that we're using the Document Providers as our site is an MVC site that's pulling it's content from Kentico, so I'm not making a direct database query.

Comment: You can still have this in your OrderBy clause with DocumentQueries.

Comment: Right, I'm asking what the OrderBy clause should be for this.

Comment: I posted it in my answer.  `Order By CASE WHEN NodeLevel == 1 THEN NodeName ELSE '' END`

Comment: Oh... sorry, Brenden. I was looking on my phone and didn't see the original answer, only the comment. That's a cool answer. I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could join the pages (documents) using `NodeParentID`:

```sql
SELECT t1.[NodeID]
      ,t1.[NodeAliasPath]
      ,t1.[NodeName]
      ,t1.[NodeAlias]
      ,t1.[NodeParentID]
      ,t1.[NodeLevel]
      ,t1.[NodeOrder]
      ,t2.[NodeAliasPath] AS [ParentPath]
      ,t2.[NodeOrder] AS [ParentOrder]
      ,t2.[NodeLevel] AS [ParentLevel]
  FROM [CMS_Tree] t1
  INNER JOIN [CMS_Tree] t2 ON
  t1.[NodeParentID] = t2.[NodeID]
  ORDER BY [ParentOrder]
```

And order the data using parent's `NodeOrder` or `NodeAliasPath`.

It should be possible to perform the join even via API:

```c#
DocumentNodeDataInfoProvider.GetDocumentNodes()
  .Source(sourceItem => sourceItem.Join<DocumentNodeDataInfo>("NodeParentID", "NodeID"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @rocky. I should have mentioned that we're using Kentico's MVC solution and not making direct DB calls. Sorry about the confusion.